# clock() function doesn't measure qsort() time

Tags: c, clock, qsort, time.h, time-t

I'm trying to write a program that takes some song data (~1000 lines) from a CSV file and puts it into a struct array. Each line from that CSV file contains: `title of the song`, `artist` and `release year`. String, string and int.

No problems when taking out the data.

The lines are correctly written inside my struct array (called `s`), and also the `bubblesort` part works fine. Calculating the execution time for bubblesort also works. I write that time in the memory.

I'm resetting the array after that, and the data is again inserted into the array struct. I'm using `qsort()` to sort the array. The function does what it is intended to do. The array is sorted the same as it was sorted by `bubblesort`. The problem is, time measured is `0,000...`.

That's my `bubblesortTime()` function that returns the execution time needed for the bubblesort... sort:

```
float bubbleSortTime(song *s, int length) {
    int flag;
    song aux;

    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();

    do {
        flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j<length-1; j++) {
            if (s[j].release_year > s[j+1].release_year) {
                aux = s[j];
                s[j] = s[j+1];
                s[j+1] = aux;
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 1);

    end = clock();

    clock_t time = end-start;
    float finTime = (float)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


    return finTime;
}
```

also, that's my `qsortTime()` function, together with `comp()`:

```
int comp (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    song *s1 = (song *)a;
    song *s2 = (song *)b;

    return (s1->release_year - s2->release_year);
}

float qsortTime(song *s, int length) {

    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();

    qsort(s, length, sizeof(s[0]), comp);

    end = clock();

    clock_t time = end-start;
    float finTime = (float)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    return finTime;
}
```

When displaying the two returned values in `main()`, using:

```
float time1 = bubbleSortTime(s, i);

/** 
reset code and more things here
**/

float time2 = qsortTime(s, i);
printf("%f %f", time1, time2);
```

(...) the output is: `0.062500 0.000000`, stating the fact that the time for the `bubblesort` call was properly calculated, while the time for the `qsort` call wasn't.

I know that `qsort` is usually slower than `bubblesort`, and that's why I'm confused.

If you need me to provide more code, please leave a comment and I'll do it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Quicksort is usually faster than bubble sort. Quicksort averages O(n log n), bubblesort is O(n^2).

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/

Comment: Try testing with much larger arrays.

Comment: You can't really use `clock()` for comparing such short time spans, because of its granularity. It is a blunt tool.

Comment: As @Barmar suggests, or repeat the call to `qsort()` multiple times while measuring the time. Then divide the time by the number of times `qsort()` was executed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The difference is stored in a `clock_t` variable. The division through `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is converted to float only.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's a Uni assignment I received. Teacher says we can measure these time spans.

Comment: @VisionCorporations Why yes it is!

Comment: Aside: In case the `float` value less than 0.000001` use `"%g"` or `"%e"` for more information than `"%f"`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You mean after calculating the `float finTime` to `printf("%e", ...)`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Result still didn't change. Still 0, unfortunately

Comment: @jxh That would make it hard for me, because I'll need to reinitialize the array every time I do this.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Should I edit the question, providing the full code, in case there might be a problem with other functions?

Comment: Review the goals of a [mcve]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Tried sorting an array with `100,000` random elements generated by the `rand()%1000` function. Execution time of `qsort()` was also 0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Could it also be the fact that my computer has 16GB RAM?

Comment: Don't you have your answer? You *can* make slower sorting functions but bubble sort is about the worst performer of the commonly used ones. The `qsort` was so much faster that the `clock()` time measurement was `0`. On MS Visual C `clock()` counts in 1/1000 seconds (smaller on Linux, perhaps). The standard does not state its resolution, and I remember when it was about 1/18 second. It is irrelevant what else the `struct` contains, as you are comparing `int` members and swapping the *pointers*.

Comment: Vision Corporations, I suspect your N (e.g. 100,000) is too small.  Double it and try again. and the double again, etc.

Comment: It is best to use a well-known benchmarking and test library like this one https://github.com/google/benchmark

Comment: Or if you're on a Linux you could use `apt install libbenchmark-dev libgtest-dev` or 
`dnf install google-benchmark-devel gtest-devel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a larger N.

First try exercising just `qsortTime()` with larger N.

with N = 100,000 and reported times of "0.062500 0.000000" and O(`n*n`) vs O(`n*log n`), the time difference between the 2 algorithms can well exceed a factor of 1000.

For me, with `N = 100,000` it was

```
Bubble: 47.125
QTSort: 0.016
```

Also, be sure "reset code and more things here" includes giving `qsortTime(s, i);` an unsorted list and not the list sorted by `bubbleSortTime()`.

Example

```
#define SS (100000 * 2)
song s[SS];

int main() {
  // for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++)
  //  s[i].release_year = rand() % 1000;
  // printf("Bubble: %g\n", bubbleSortTime(s, SS));
  for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++)
    s[i].release_year = rand() % 1000;
  printf("QTSort: %g\n", qsortTime(s, SS));
}
```

Comment: Yup. The "reset code and more things here" has restored the struct array to its initial state. No problems with that. My classmate also tried to run my code on his MacOS, the `qsortTime` was `!= 0.000...`. That means, it also has to do with the computer that runs it. Also, marked this answer as the proper one.